# How to review this type of question: Questioner answered his question as a comment

Tags: discussion, review

Questioner answered his question as a comment and edited the title with [SOLVED] postfix.

Example:

Title: Something wrong [SOLVED]
Q: Something wrong.....
Comment: I solved the problem (less then a line).

**What is the best ways to review this type of questions?**

In my view the best think is answer his / her own question and then accept it.
- In this case maybe the system converts the answer to comment (as I know there is a trivial answer to comment feature, maybe that happened).

Why is he / her edit the title with [SOLVED] postfix?
- I don't know ...

Should I mark with flag to delete, or mark for moderator attention, or send a message to request an edit?

**Edit:**

[Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618683/problems-while-using-egit-pluginsolved)

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your advice, I edited my post with a link to an SO question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, things you can do:

1. Remove `[Solved]` from the title.
2. If there is a solution inside of the question itself, remove the solution from the question.
3. If there is no answer posted, but there is enough content to make up a real answer between the question and the comments, make a new answer to represent that content.  Make sure to cite the author where appropriate when using their own content.  While not required, I would personally suggest marking such an answer as "community wiki" if it doesn't contain any original content from yourself and is merely quoting the author.  If you are taking what they have and adding enough of your original content to really feel that it's *your* answer, feel free to not CW the answer.

Now in the case of the specific example you listed, (and take this with a grain of salt as it's not my area of expertise) the "answer" seems a bit light on content.  I'd say that it should really be flushed out a bit before you'd want to post an answer; that comment alone doesn't seem sufficient.  Ideally you, the OP, or someone else will come along and use that comment to create a detailed answer with sufficient explanation.

Comment: @Servy This is a very clear answer, thank you for your help!